# Get ipv6 static address teredo

Tags: ipv6, teredo

I have a server behind NAT, which I want to be able to access from the internet. I want to do it over ipv6. I guess my question falls into two:

1. I don't think teredo is working on it. I have ethernet adapter ipv6 [set to automatic](http://vvcap.net/db/01v_HmAUdvPqPM5kiCEp.htp), however I [don't think there connectivity is there](http://vvcap.net/db/CMYY0HWcLQRL5LTukoxS.htp). So, how do I enable teredo to get a publicly accessible ipv6 address?
2. Is it possible to claim a static address in teredo, so that every time I connect the address stays the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not really. teredo is sort of like nat - you can access IPV6, but the address, iirc is link local. performance is terrible to boot.

Its probably simpler to get a tunnel, and set that up - gogo6 definately works behind a nat, for example.

Comment: Teredo works fine, only caveat is DNS will not use it, you must use literal IPv6 addressing.